# Swift – Importing ARKit module

Tags: objective-c, arkit

I am trying to import ARKit to Swift using bridge file but for some reason that I don't understand, Swift cannot recognise the ARKit and gives an error:

```
// No such module 'ARKit'
```

My bridge file:

```
#ifndef Ligo_Header_h
#define Ligo_Header_h
#import "ARKit/ARKit.h"
```

Then I import ARkit in my `ViewController.swift` class

```
import ARKit
```

wired is that auto compilation recognises all ARKit delegates and classes but I cant get rid of this error.

Also bridge file setting in build phases is pointing to the right file.

I really appreciate some help here.

Comment: try "#import "ARKit.h" or #import <ARKit/ARKit.h>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

There was no need to import ARKit in ViewController Class or any other swift class. Importing .h in Header file will automatically make it accessible to all swift files.

Comment: Have you successfully added the ARToolKit library to your Swift project ? If so, I'd love to hear the procedure because even with the bridging header my project won't compile